# I'm trying to read json data and it is returning "false"

Tags: nsarray, nsurl, json

Here is my code that is returning a false instead of the json array count.
I must comment that at one point it was working and then it stopped. Please help.

```
            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

                let urlError = false

                if error == nil {

                    let urlContent = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSString!

                    let data: NSData = urlContent.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

                    print("data here\(data)”) // I see a lot of data in the logs with this print

                    do {

                        let jsonObject = try (NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSArray)!

                    print(“here is the array count\(jsonObject.count)”) // it never prints this to the logs. What I get is “false"

                    …The rest of the code...
```

Comment: It is boiling down to this statement:

Comment: let jsonObject = try (NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSArray)!

Comment: Any idea why this would return "false"